# How do I convert a WWWForm that will be a parameter for UploadHandlerRaw into a byte array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a class that inherited UnityWebRequest.
It just has `string url`, `string method`, and `byte[] form` as parameters.
I want to put WWWForm Object in this `byte[] form`. When I checked the metadata, it seems that the WWWForm is composed of a Dictionary.
If I could check the Unity internal source code, I would have solved it myself, but I couldn't.
How can I solve this problem?I want to use `WWWForm` for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. I want to find a way to convert WWWForm to Byte Array. Sorry. I am very poor at English. Please let me know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find a way to convert WWWForm to Byte Array

This can be done with the [`WWWForm.data`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-data.html) property.

Your `WWWForm`:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField( "blah-blah-blah", "value" );
```

Convert the `WWWForm` to byte array:

```
byte[] rawData = form.data;
```

---

To use it with `UploadHandlerRaw`:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("blah-blah-blah", "value");
byte[] rawData = form.data;

string url = "YOUR URL";
var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
uwr.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(rawData);
uwr.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
uwr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//Send the request then wait here until it returns
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

if (uwr.isNetworkError)
{
    Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

Comment: Great! If I had looked at the metadata better, I could have solved it. Thank you very much.